# Java to Python with Java2Python

Tags: java, python

I am using Java2Python package to translate a Java project to Python, and I've got an error.

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# j2py ConfigurationManager.java ConfigurationManager.py
      File "/usr/bin/j2py", line 113
        except (IOError, ), exc:
                          ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

File /usr/bin/j2py, line 113

try:
    if filein != '-':
        source = open(filein).read()
    else:
        source = sys.stdin.read()
except (IOError, ), exc:
    code, msg = exc.args[0:2]
    print 'IOError: %s.' % (msg, )
    return code
```

If there is any information needed, please tell me.

---

update

```
 File "/usr/bin/j2py", line 115
    print 'IOError: %s.' % (msg, )
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You should read the documentation of the tool you are using.

Comment: @Stultuske it seems like the python code in it goes wrong..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java to python translation with java2python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50366602/java-to-python-translation-with-java2python)

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko I have just deleted that question

Comment: @mathews yes, but is it a known problem in the tool? is it a problem in your java code? ...

Comment: no any information about this tool yet..the java code is running on product environment and is well

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
except (IOError) as exc:
        for arg in exc.args:
           print(str(arg))
        code = exc.args[0]
        return code
```

Here I assume that you want to return 1st value in `exc.args`

Comment: try putting the print statement in paranthesis like `print(whatever you want to print)`